# How can I use .NET framework 4.5 in Unity 5

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unity-game-engine

I'm working with **unity3D 5**. And I wanna import external **my** **KinectDB.dll** (includes my sql server db functions with entityframework. And it was complied with **.NET 4.5 framework**) class library to unity. But unity console gives me an error like below. I searched for this problem many hours. But I can't reach to complete solution.  How can I solve this? What are your advices? Thanks in advance.

**Hint :** I created an example project with ***.NET 3.5 framework***. And I import it to unity. Unity doesnt give me an error in this case.

```
  Unhandled Exception: System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: The classes in the module cannot be loaded.

  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.Assembly:GetTypes (bool)

  at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Mono.CSharp.RootNamespace.ComputeNamespaces (System.Reflection.Assembly assembly, System.Type extensionType) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Mono.CSharp.RootNamespace.ComputeNamespace (Mono.CSharp.CompilerContext ctx, System.Type extensionType) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Mono.CSharp.GlobalRootNamespace.ComputeNamespaces (Mono.CSharp.CompilerContext ctx) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Mono.CSharp.Driver.LoadReferences () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Mono.CSharp.Driver.Compile () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Mono.CSharp.Driver.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

Missing method .ctor in assembly -------\Assets\KinectDB.dll, type System.Runtime.Versioning.TargetFrameworkAttribute
The class System.Runtime.Versioning.TargetFrameworkAttribute could not be loaded, used in KinectDB
Can't find custom attr constructor image: Assets\KinectDB.dll mtoken: 0x0a00000e
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only wait till Unity updates its bundled Mono to 4.x. It is already on their roadmap. With Microsoft licenses Mono runtime from LGPL to MIT and Unity joined .NET Foundation, it is likely that such a platform upgrade might come sooner.

http://unity3d.com/unity/roadmap

Comment: I see a lot of comments about this, concretly what kind of improvements will we get ?

Comment: @FLX for all current platforms based on Mono and .NET, Unity is the only one left behind, so that the upcoming benefits from .NET/Mono (such as async/await, .NET Standard Library, and so on) cannot be applied to Unity. Also the most of .NET libraries are moving to .NET 4.5, which means you cannot use them or their latest versions on Unity. Thus, the collaboration among Unity/Mono/Microsoft under .NET Foundation is now critical and I believe the top priority is to upgrade Unity with latest Mono. After that all benefits come.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. If not already seen, you will like this : http://blogs.unity3d.com/2016/04/01/unity-joins-the-net-foundation/ :)

Comment: @AbleArcher Can you, please, quote it? I don't see anything related to C#/Mono/.NET in the roadmap =(

Comment: Look [here](https://unity3d.com/unity/roadmap). Under the 2017.1.0 (beta) heading there is a bullet point for Scripting Runtime Upgrade.

Comment: "Upgrade Mono and IL2CPP .NET runtimes to support the latest .NET functionality and APIs. This includes access to C# 6 and the .NET 4.6.x class library profile."
Thanks, @AbleArche
It's planned for July release

Answer (score 0):

Yeah. It all starts with reading the documentation - and realizing that Unity uses a quite outdated version of .NET. You CAN NOT use 4.5 libraries in Unity. What you CAN do is run them in a separate program and communicate with this program via network etc. - but that is a LOT of work.

Once in the future Unity will upgrade. But they have not yet.

Comment: Write webservice is a suitable alternative way for this case?

Comment: Depends on what you are doing. For some thing web services may be too - way too - slow. For other things they are fine.